# Android ContentResolver doesn't load the Song-Titles

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

My App should load the Media-Tags from the Songs, stored on the Device's storage, but the displayed Names are the File-Names and not the Title-Tags!

My Code:

```
List<Song> SongList = new ArrayList<>();

ContentResolver musicResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

Cursor cSong = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

int iIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
int iTitleCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
int iArtistCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
int iAlbumCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
int iDurationCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
int iAlbumIDCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
int iDataCol = cSong.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

if (cSong != null && cSong.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String sArtist = cSong.getString(iArtistCol);
        String sAlbum = cSong.getString(iAlbumCol);

        if (sArtist.equals(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING)) {
            sArtist = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.UnknownArtist);
        }

        if (sAlbum.equals(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING)) {
            sAlbum = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.UnknownAlbum);
        }

        SongList.add(new Song(cSong.getLong(iIDCol), cSong.getLong(iAlbumIDCol), cSong.getString(iTitleCol), sArtist, sAlbum, cSong.getInt(iDurationCol), cSong.getString(iDataCol)));
    }
    while (cSong.moveToNext());
}

cSong.close();
```

#Selfie is displayed correctly because the Filename equals the Song-Title, but the others aren't displayed correctly!

[image]

**EDIT:**

**I checked out that only non-MP3-Files cause problems! How can I fix this?**

I hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is you have not set the projection argument for getContentResolver.query() method

Try this

```
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cSong = musicResolver.query(musicUri,new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA},null,null,null);
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything! please note my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the title, etc:

```
String data = cursor.getString(iDataCol)
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(data);

String title = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

You can get the artist & album too

Comment: This causes a very long starting time of my application... is there any other possibility?

Comment: and the problem isn't solved at all, the error is still there

Comment: Unfortunately it does take a while.  I've only ever used it directly with the files themselves rather than the content provider and it has returned the correct data.  It seems maybe content provider is the cause of the spurious data!

Comment: no, i think the problem is caused by wma & m4a files! please check my edit!